# Why script continue excuting after an error in a promise

Tags: javascript

i have this promise without error handler

```js
new Promise(function() {
  noSuchFunction(); // Error here (no such function)
})
.then(() => {

});


console.log("why this code is executed ?? ");
```

i don't understand why the script does not crash and continue executing after the error

Comment: Because the error is contained within the promise chain. The promise chain fails, not the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are designed to handle asynchronous code, so they have to provide a mechanism for errors to be handled asynchronously. Consequently, they capture all errors (similar to a `try`/`catch` block) and pass them along the promise chain.

```js
const promise = new Promise(function() {
    noSuchFunction(); // Error here (no such function)
  })
  .then(() => {

  });


console.log("why this code is executed ?? ");

promise.catch( error => console.log(error.message) );
```